# SetInterval() with "if" condition in js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to continuously call the function below using `setInterval()` but only if the condition in the if statement evaluates to true. 
**Note:** The function is global.

```
function view_stack(){
    if(my_stack.size() > 0){
        document.getElementById("stack_visual").innerHTML = my_stack.view();
    } else {
        swal("Ohhhh Noes", "There are no items in the stack!", "error");
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve it?

Comment: You need to be clear do you want to set the interval if the condition is true or do you only want to execute it if its true. These are two different things

Comment: I would like to execute it. Thanks for the clarification @Dellirium

Comment: Just call the function on the interval then, `setInterval(view_stack, 1000);` your function checks to see if the stack size is there and does one or the other depending on it, all you need to do is call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it so that your function does nothing when there is nothing to do. That way you can simply keep the interval running.

Effectively your code already is written like that, I would rearrange it like this:

```
function view_stack(){
    if(my_stack.size() === 0) return;
    document.getElementById("stack_visual").innerHTML = my_stack.view();
}

setInterval(view_stack, 1000);
```

The more elegant solution would be event-based, i.e. whenever `my_stack` changes, update the view.

Answer (score 2):

You could put an if statement in the setInterval function like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(my_stack.size() > 0) {
    view_stack();
  }
}, 1000/60);
```

So, only if `my_stack.size() > 0` it will then call the `view_stack()` function.

Note `setInterval()` is triggered 60 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply nest your function within a setTimeout nested within a while loop.

```js
function view_stack(){

  while(my_stack.size() > 0){
  
    setTimeout(() => {
    
      document.getElementById("stack_visual").innerHTML = my_stack.view();
    
    ), 1000} //for a second rhythm.
  
  }
  
  swal("Ohhhh Noes", "There are no items in the stack!", "error");

}
```

this way the function will work only if "true" and still have control over the rhythm it works.